# Harddrive crashed, bought new bigger harddrive, but will not load from recovery disks?

Tags: windows, windows-vista

My HP Media center harddrive crashed. I was told I could buy a new harddrive and reload from recovery disks copied off the system when I orignially bought the machine.  My brother-in-law is trying to run the recovery and it stops towards the end. Message says "Windows Setup could not configure Windows to run on this computer's hardware".  Any suggestions?? It is windows Vista.

It is a WD 1TB drive

It is a HP M9340f Media Center

Comment: It is a WD 1TB drive

Comment: It is a HP M9340f Media Center.

Comment: 2Tb is the largest physical drive Vista can handle so 1Tb should be fine...

Comment: See [this Dell web page](http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/kcs/document?c=us&docid=416677&l=en&s=gen#Issue3). More general information is [here](http://support.dell.com/support/topics/topic.aspx/global/shared/support/hard_drive_support/hard-drive). Changing the BIOS settings for AHCI/IDE mode might help too.

Comment: @BobT: "2Tb is the largest physical drive Vista can handle" - Unless of course you install it on a UEFI + GPT machine.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use the same hard drive model as your dead one. Unless you've tried the recovery, some recovery software is not as flexible such as using a different model or size hard drive. I use acronis easy image and that one is better about copying a hard drive to a different hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

What size is your new hard drive?

HP's recovery instructions [here](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00814731&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&product=3453999#N540) state that you need to disconnect *all* external devices before trying to recover.

*"With the computer off, disconnect all connected devices and cables such as the Personal Media Drive, USB drives, printer, and fax. Remove media from drives, and remove any recently added internal hardware. Do not disconnect the monitor, keyboard, mouse, and power cord."*

If you haven't done this then that may be the source of your problem... I think the intent is to return the computer to the hardware state it was in when you created the recovery media. You might also check [here](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00881405&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&product=3740326#N606) for troubleshooting system recovery problems on your particular system.

Comment: It is a 1TB drive. Everything is disconnected.

Comment: Thanks Guys!  Got it.  It was trying to read it as a RAID (so had to change the bios) and then it loaded fine.  Thanks!!